# Spark path on Windows/Java: Why does a directory path work but a specific file fail?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am attempting to follow "Creating Dataframes" example found here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#overview

I am doing this in Java 8 on Windows and the following line of code:

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("c:/sparkExamples/");
```

works while:

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("c:/sparkExamples/people.json");
```

Fails with this exception:

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: file:/c:/sparkExamples/people.json;

From the example, it appears that specifying a file should work.

Comment: Is there a json file there? The directory probably exists, but do you get any data with example one?

Comment: Perhaps because the method only supports paths which it then scans for files ?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: The file is indeed there and when I try the first approach, the df.show() method works as expected from the example. The example seems to indicate that a file is possible to be specified.

Comment: @Marged: The example code is: Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("examples/src/main/resources/people.json"); That is, a file is there. This seems to be for Unix and maybe this is some limitation of Windows. I have tried Windows-style paths with no better result.